# Error when backing up from SQL Server 2014 to Azure blob storage

Tags: sql-server-2014, backup, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to back up a SQL Server 2014 database to Azure blob storage. However, I'm getting the below error when trying to do so.

> A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file
> "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/MyDB.bak:"
> Backup to URL received an exception from the remote endpoint.
> Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (403)
> Forbidden..

Initially, I assumed I'd made a mistake with either the credential, the name of either the Storage Account, or the Container. However, when I tried backing up a database from a SQL Server 2019 instance, it worked fine.

I've spent several hours trying to find a solution and I've made no no further progress. So, I'm looking for a bit of help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the problem was backing up to a container in a v2 Storage Account. SQL Server 2014 obviously doesnt like that. I got a v1 Storage Account provisioned and backups are now working.

Thanks again to anyone who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the clock on the servers in question. Apart from the incorrect account key, you can also get 403 error if the time on the server is not in sync with the time on storage servers (Give or take +/- 15 minutes deviation is allowed).

Another problem could come from your enterprise proxy which can block the connection to Azure storage account.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions. I did come across the potential time sync error in an article as well so I'll check that out. Not sure what you mean by 'Enterprise proxy' though. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your company proxy, azure storage as to be placed in the proxy exceptions.